# IRONPDF taking 3 minutes to convert html to PDF

Tags: c#

I am using below code to convert HTML to PDF using IRONPDF, but it is taking more than 3 minutes to get converted on application server , i am using :
1. License version 
2. a simple html file to convert into pdf

```
        var infolder = textBox1.Text.Trim();
        var outfolder = textBox2.Text.Trim();

        var Renderer = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
        var PDF = Renderer.RenderHTMLFileAsPdf(infolder);
        PDF.SaveAs(outfolder);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should make sure that any external links (e.g. stylesheets, javascript) can be resolved from the machine where the rendering is happening.  An easy way to check is to open the html file on that machine with a browser.

In our case, our staging environment was going through a load-balancer and the underlying servers couldn't resolve the name (e.g. https://staging-myapp.company.com).  We used a public gateway in our case but you could also modify your hosts file for your address to resolve locally (edit the hosts file with extreme caution!).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you Try to do in batches or for high performance. you can use `Async` and `Threading`

```
private async Task <IronPdf.PdfDocument>RenderPdfAsync( string Html , IronPdf.PdfPrintOptions PrintOptions = null )
{
  var Renderer = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
  if(PrintOptions!=null){
    Renderer.PrintOptions = PrintOptions;
  }
  return Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf(Html);
}
```

> Task.Run requires.Net Framework 4.5+

Or `Using Parallel.ForEach`

For high performance, IronPDF support `multithreading`. The easiest way to achieve this by using the native command `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: https://ironpdf.com/examples/parallel/ <-- this worked as Sunil suggested